# Oracle XE 18c DBFS_CLIENT auth failing for SYS without SYSDBA privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-18c

I have been following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_client.htm#ADLOB45997) tutorial to setup an Oracle DBFS environment for testing.

A certain step of the tutorial is pointing to the use of the DBFS_CLIENT:

[image: DBFS_CLIENT]

When I try to authenticate on the dbfs_client using the "sys" credentials, it returns an error: **The connection as SYS must have SYSDBA or SYSOPER privileges**.

[image: DBFS_CLIENT_ERROR]

I understand that the privilege is granted by simply adjusting the "sys" credentials I wrote on the command line.

What am I doing wrong there? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "_What am I doing wrong there?_" -- connecting as `sys`. Don't start a bad habit.

Comment: I just want to test DBFS to see how it works locally on my machine. I mean no harm

Comment: Create a separate Oracle user for that then.

Comment: Shouldnt I be able to log in with sys?